# Statistical significance of SVD least squares

Tags: linear-regression, dimensionality-reduction

I was not able to find any info on how least squares using singular value decomposition should be statistically evaluated. I have a dataset for which I did both multivariate regression and regression using SVD. If I use every variable of the dataset, the multivariate regression is not significant and it has some autocorrelation. Still, the SVD gets a nice fit.
If I remove some variables so that the multivariate regression works, SVD model won't be good anymore. This led me to wonder how I should be testing the SVD model?